# How to update Tkinter Progressbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm writing some code to check VAT-IDs using a web API. Since some files have quite a large amount of API-calls it sometimes takes quite a while to complete and I want to show a progressbar so other users know that the program hasn't crashed yet. I found an example and modified it slightly so that it fits my needs. This code shows a window with a progressbar and once the `for` loop is finished the window closes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

def wrap():

    MAX = 30000

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 100))
    progress_var = tk.IntVar() #here you have ints but when calc. %'s usually floats
    theLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Sample text to show")
    theLabel.pack()
    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=progress_var, maximum=MAX)
    progressbar.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1)


    def loop_function():

        k = 0
        for k in range(MAX):
        ### some work to be done
            progress_var.set(k)
            time.sleep(0.002)
            root.update()
        root.destroy()

    root.after(100, loop_function)
    root.mainloop()

wrap()
```

Now I wanted to implement this into my tool:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import pyvat
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def vatchecker(dataframe):
    #initialise progressbar
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 100))
    progress_var = tk.DoubleVar() #here you have ints but when calc. %'s usually floats
    theLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Calling VAT Api")
    theLabel.pack()
    maxval = len(dataframe['Vat-ID'])
    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=progress_var, maximum=maxval)
    progressbar.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1)
    checked =[]
    def loop_function():
        for row in range(len(dataframe['Vat-ID'])):
            print("Vatcheck: " + str(round(row/maxval * 100, 2)) + " %")
            if pd.isna(dataframe['Vat-ID'][row]):
                checked.append('No Vat Number')
            else:
                #check if vat id contains country code
                groups = re.match(r'[A-Z][A-Z]', dataframe['Vat-ID'][row])
                if groups != None:
                    querystring = dataframe['Vat-ID'][row][:-2]
                    country = dataframe['Vat-ID'][row][-2:]
                #else get VAT-ID from Country ISO
                else:
                    querystring = dataframe['Vat-ID'][row]
                    country = dataframe['Land-ISO2'][row]
                try:
                    result = pyvat.check_vat_number(str(querystring), str(country))
                    checked.append(result.is_valid)
                except:
                    checked.append('Query Error')
            progress_var.set(row)
            root.update()
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
    root.after(100, loop_function)
    root.mainloop()
    dataframe['Vat-ID-check'] = checked
    return dataframe
```

This function gets called by the main script. Here the progressbar window is shown yet the bar doesn't fill up.
With `print("Vatcheck: " + str(round(row/maxval * 100, 2)) + " %")` I can still track the progress but it's slightly ugly.

Earlier in the main script the user already interacts with a Tkinter GUI but afterwards I close those windows and loops with `root.destroy()' and 'root.quit()` so I think it should be fine to run another Tkinter instance like this?

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Calling `Tk()` more than once over the lifetime of a program is problematic - one issue is that a Tk Var may get created in a different instance of Tk than the widget you want to be controlled by it, in which case they don't interact at all.  That can be fixed by explicitly creating Vars in the proper instance - `progress_var = tk.DoubleVar(root)` for example.

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 0):

as @jasonharper mentioned above changing `progress_var = tk.DoubleVar()` to `progress_var = tk.DoubleVar(root)` works